# Get image or image url on select that image

Tags: javascript, image, onselect, imageurl

How can i get the image or image url on select that image using javascript, any examples?

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: Oh, **THAT** image... Please clarify your question.

Comment: I need to get images from other websites using an external script on browser.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is far from clear, but assuming an image with an `id` of `myImage`, and assuming that by "select" you mean "click", you can do this:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.src);
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dfheU/). Clarify your question and I can clarify my answer.

Comment: `addEventListener("click", function () { console.log(this.src); })`

Comment: Actually I'm developing a "digg" like site,so i need to get images from other websites using an external script

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward using jQuery:

```
$('#image_id').attr('src')
```

This will return the src url of the image with the id of "image_id".

If you want this information on a click event, you can wire that up like this:

```
$('#image_id').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('src')); 
});
```